# Upgrade to firefox snap

Tags: upgrade, firefox, snap

During the update it continues to pop up a little thing saying "'Frontend' is not responding" as well as saying I can wait for it or force stop, I have been waiting on this to update for over an hour and I continue to hit the wait option yet it still is not updating. What do I do to get it to update

Answer (score 1):

Reboot Ubuntu and try updating the snap packages again with the following command:

```
sudo snap refresh
```